# Apply code on every row of a result of a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I need to `SELECT FROM` a mysql database and the result can be 0 or more rows.

For a certain column and for every row I need to do an `UPDATE` statement on a different table using this column.

How can I achieve this in the most efficient way?

Comment: I could loop through the results and create the `UPDATE` statement on every cycle.

Comment: can i see your code or your table structure

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do sounds like an `update` with a `join`.  Something like this:

```
update table2 t2 join
       table1 t1
       on t2.col = t1.col and t1.val = @val
    set t2.col2 = 1;
```

Comment: This look nice, but I only need to do the update not only when `t2.col = t1.col` but when additionally t1.col has a certain value.